# Does anyone know whats the issue with this code

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

```
-(NSData *) decryptData:(NSData *) Data
{
NSData *iv;
NSData *salt;
NSError *error;
NSData *stringData = Data;

NSInputStream *inpStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithData:stringData];
bool IVData = [inpStream _CMgetData:&iv maxLength:kAlgorithmIVSize error:&error];
bool SaltData = [inpStream _CMgetData:&salt maxLength:kPBKDFSaltSize error:&error];
}

@implementation NSInputStream (Data)

-(BOOL)_CMgetData:(NSData **)data maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxLength error:(NSError **)error {

NSMutableData *buffer = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:maxLength];
if ([self read:buffer.mutableBytes maxLength:maxLength] < 0)
{
    if (error)
    {
        *error = [self streamError];
        NSLog(@"CMgetData Error!!");
        return NO;
    }
}

*data = buffer;
NSLog(@"%@", buffer);
return YES;
}

@end
```

I always get "CMgetData Error!!" Does anyone know why this issue comming.. I believe i passed all the parameters correctly. is that right?? Please help
Thanks in advance Any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any stream must be opened before you can read from or write to it:

```
NSInputStream *inpStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithData:stringData];
[inpStream open];
// now you can read from the stream.
```

Answer (score 1):

In decrypt data you create a pointer to an NSError. This pointer gets an adress somewhere in memory and you pass that adress to _CMgetData. That adress will always evaluate to true, therefore (when read returns a negative number) you always enter the if(error) block.

You probably want to check whether your call to read:maxLength: had an error, as it returns with a negative number. Check the specs of that function how to retrieve error information.

Comment: :- u saying that i need to call _CMgetData in an if condition like
    if(![inpStream _CMgetData:&iv maxLength:kAlgorithmIVSize error:&error] || ![inpStream _CMgetData:&salt maxLength:kPBKDFSaltSize error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"_CMgetData error");
        return NO;
    }

Comment: No. I supposedly only answered your question and made no suggestions whatsoever how you should deal with it correctly. That would be a different question and would require more info about the read: function.

Comment: I think the read function is a predefined one in NSStream.h
function declaration is like this. - (NSInteger)read:(uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)len; also i cant find the definition of this function. Do i need to write my one definition?? if yes can u help me for writing the function.. thanks for ur help.. much appreciate :)

Comment: Read the NSInputStream class reference.

Answer (score 0):

For non-ARC code, local variables, particularly `NSError` instances that you are later checking for non-nil status, must be initialised to nil, otherwise they will hold garbage. Declare as:

```
NSError *error = nil;
```

Instead.

Comment: It might be wrong, but I think with ARC that is not necessary anymore, all local object variables are automatically initialized to `nil`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm working on an MRC codebase at the moment and had gone back into history mode. Thanks!